# Focal length to Field of view

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm importing some 3D models from Rhino 3D to Unity. When doing that I need to import the camera views. In Rhino they have the property Focal length and in Unity we have Field of view.
I need to convert focal length to Field of View. I found a formula to convert the values here
http://paulbourke.net/miscellaneous/lens/

I'm planning to use this formula
vertical field of view = 2 atan(0.5 height / focal length)
My question is how can I find the value for the height. I'm not sure from where I can get that in Unity.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Maths isn't my strong suit but I do recall the formula was used in a certain BFBC2 [fov tool](http://www.rjdown.co.uk/projects/bfbc2/fovcalculator.php)

`hFov = 2 * atan(tan( vFov/2 ) * width/height)`

Where width and height are your current screen resolution dimensions.
I hope this is correct for your purpose.

Answer (score 2):

To answer my question, this is the formula I ended up using at the end. Hope that'll be useful for anyone having a similar issue.

Code in C# in Unity

```
// Standard film size
int filmHeight = 24;
int filmWidth = 36;

// Formula to convert focalLength to field of view - In Unity they use Vertical FOV.
// So we use the filmHeight to calculate Vertical FOV.
double fovdub = Mathf.Rad2Deg * 2.0 * Math.Atan(filmHeight  / (2.0 * focalLen));
float fov = (float) fovdub;
```